# Pass bitmab back from activity to fragment

Tags: java, android

I have a fragment that contains an image view and button when I click on the button am going to an activity that has an image as a bitmap and in the activity, I have a button (save) that should finish the activity and go back to the fragment with the bitmap data.

I tried to use intents and bundles but nothing worked.

Comment: if the fragment attached to activity then it is also destroyed with activity destroy via finish call. Add more explanation to your question.

Comment: I think you should convert it to ByteArray. And use putString. And get it in another fragment.

Comment: Your code please. It is probably very simple to solve your problem if you show us your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up using this approach:

1. in your fragment:

   ```
    Intent signatureIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), SignatureActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(signatureIntent, your_request_code);

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                 @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == your_request_code&& resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){

            String received = data.getStringExtra("extra");
            byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(received, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, 
            decodedString.length);
       }
   }
   ```
2. in your activity:

   ```
    bitmap = signatureView.getSignatureBitmap();
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent();

     ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
     byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
     String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);

     resultIntent .putExtra("extra",encoded);
     setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
     finish();
   ```

Comment: and don't forget to override onAvtivityResult() in your activity

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your `Bitmap` data to an `byte` array then put it into the `Bundle`

```
ByteArrayOutputStream mStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
yourBitmapImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, mStream);
byte[] byteArray = mStream.toByteArray();

Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
mBundle.putByteArray("image",byteArray);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help it works for me using startActivityForResulte()

Answer (score 0):

Passing Bitmap Object via bundle intents is very dangerous and you may end up getting errors especially for bitmaps of uknown lengths since there is even a limit for the size of the Parcelable extra.its highly unrecomended .Better solution would be to save it to a file then the path to a String value and pass it to the next activity or even to shared prefrence just in case it might be needed even after the app closes or even needed elsewhere in your code without using up your memory.Bitmaps especially are a great threat to memory if mishandled.See

```
public class Bitmap_saver{


public static String my_bitmap_path(Context act) {

    SharedPreferences prefs = act.getSharedPreferences("SHAREDpREFname", act.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return prefs.getString("my_bitmap_address", null);

}

public static void set_my_bitmap_address(Context act, String path) {

    SharedPreferences.Editor saver = act.getSharedPreferences("SHAREDpREFname", act.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

    saver.putString("my_bitmap_address", path);
    saver.commit();

}
public static String save_to_file(Bitmap fpb)
{
    String img_name="BIT_"+ System.currentTimeMillis()+".JPG";

    OutputStream fOutputStream = null;

    File file = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/YOUR_APP_DATA/");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        Log.e("Creating data dir=>",""+ String.valueOf(file.mkdirs()));
    }

    file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/YOUR_APP_DATA/", img_name);

    try {
        fOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

        fpb.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOutputStream);

        fOutputStream.flush();
        fOutputStream.close();


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

         return "error";
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        //   Toast.makeText(this, "Save Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return "error";
    }
    return file.getAbsolutePath();
}

}
```

Call it like this to save `Bitmap_saver.set_my_bitmap_path(your_context,Bitmap_saver.save_to_file(your_bitmap));`

from your retreiving fragment/activity/class call this `Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Bitmap_saver.my_bitmap_path(your_context));`

Comment: Thank you for your solution but it's not a good way to save paths in sharedpreference, imagine you have 100 image.